# Understanding closure scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, theory

I've been reading the "You Don't Know JS" book series and I have a question regarding **closures**.

```js
var a;

function wait() {
  a = 10;

  return setTimeout(function timer() {
    console.log('Hello closure ', a);
  }, 1000)
}

const fn = wait;
fn();
console.log(a);
```

If I asked for the value of **a** in the console without executing the function (fn()), it will say it is **undefined** which is correct.

Now if I execute the function **fn()** after 1 second it will print **Hello Closure 10** I know that timer has a closure over wait function, that's why it prints that value, even when it is executed outside the lexical scope where it was defined.

But if a print **a** value in the console now (*after running fn()*) it output also **10** , so I guess this is not **lexical scope**, from global scope the lookup never goes down (I mean it looks deep down in the nested functions), it always look for the variables up (going up to the enclosing scopes of functions).

So I wonder if this is closure too or the variable just got another value after running the function and that's all?

Comment: Its value is staying as 10 because you set the variable in the global scope.

Comment: `function wait() {
    var a = 10;` ... ` would be different...

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiate the variable inside the function, it will prevent global variables of the same name from changing. I added a `var a = 10` into the function. I left the globally scoped var there so you can  see that now it doesn't change. This is more of a variable scoping issue.

The closure was working as you expected, just you were setting a global variable.

```js
var a;
function wait() {
  var a = 10;

  return setTimeout(function timer() {
    console.log('Hello closure ', a);
  }, 1000)
}

const fn = wait;
fn();
console.log(a);
```